# throw new RangeError node js

Tags: node.js, server, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm trying to work with IBM Watson Conversation service with Node.js. 
I use 'express' to post a message:

```
app.post( '/api/message', function(req, res) {
}
```

and to print the message got from the service:

```
 conversation.message( payload, function(err, data) {
    if ( err ) {
      return res.status( err.code || 500 ).json( err );
    }
    return res.json( updateMessage( payload, data ) );
  } );
```

I just ran the application on port 3000. While the page is not loaded and I got this error:

```
_http_server.js:192
    throw new RangeError(`Invalid status code: ${statusCode}`);
    ^

RangeError: Invalid status code: 0
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:192:11)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:157:8)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:573:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\IBM\1.Mission\2016\conversation-simple-master(1)\
conversation-simple-master\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:204:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\IBM\1.Mission\2016\conversation-simple-master(1)\
conversation-simple-master\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:249:15)
    at C:\IBM\1.Mission\2016\conversation-simple-master(1)\conversation-simple-m
aster\app.js:86:44
    at Request._callback (C:\IBM\1.Mission\2016\conversation-simple-master(1)\co
nversation-simple-master\node_modules\watson-developer-cloud\lib\requestwrapper.
js:47:7)
    at self.callback (C:\IBM\1.Mission\2016\conversation-simple-master(1)\conver
sation-simple-master\node_modules\watson-developer-cloud\node_modules\request\re
quest.js:200:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
```

I don't think the problem is from npm, back my package... While it seems a generic problem...Thanks for you help.

Comment: what code have you written? The one in app.js? you should show us then its easier to help.

Comment: @Roland, I just edited my question. I think it's a standard problem from npm, I can't get the post from the service...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request to IBM Watson Conversation service probably ended with error with code `"0"` and it isn't a valid HTTP status code. This should work:

```
conversation.message(payload, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(500).json(err);
  }

  return res.json(updateMessage(payload, data));
});
```

Comment: Thanks qzb, I don't have error message any more. But do you have any idea why some time the service returns nothing and some time it works. I've checked all the credentials and there's nothing wrong

Comment: Unfortunately I know nothing about this service, so I cannot help you :/